# Merge two different rows into single row in SQL with different pattern

Tags: sql-server, merge

I am trying to merge several records of same type into single row in SQL. Here is my sample data. I had also tried using COALESCE(Name + ',', '') AS Names, by merging them together and split them again in a common table. But, this is kind of merging row two records and doing an pivot on top of it.

Any inputs on this would be helpful. Thanks !

````
Type| Name  | Department | Value1 |  Value 2 | Value 3 
-----------------------------------------------------
1  | John  |  A         |  100   |  NULL    |  NULL
1  | John  |  B         |   NULL |  200     |  NULL
1  | John  |  C         |  NULL  |  NULL    |  300
2  | Kay   |  A         |  400   |  NULL    |  NULL
2  | Kay   |  B         |  NULL  |  500     |  NULL
3  | Lor   |  B         |  NULL  |  600     |  NULL

Edited: Apologies for not properly articulating my original problem. Updated below again.
Here is the transformation output looking after the query. Given departments can be many and they are transformed to only 3 columns in the output based on Dept Type.

ID | Name  | Department1 | Department 2| Department 3 | Value1 |  Value 2 | Value 3 
-----------------------------------------------------
1  | John  |  A         |          B   |      C       |  100   |  200    |  300
2  | Kay   |  A         |          B   |      NULL    |  400   |  500    |  NULL
3  | Lor   |  NULL      |          B   |       NULL   |  NULL  |  600    |  NULL

I was trying with below query, but i am not able to transform department values into column values. 

SELECT 
   ID, 
   MAX(Value1) AS Value1, 
   MAX(Value2) AS Value2, 
   MAX(Value3) AS Value3 
FROM Employee
GROUP BY Name ```>
````

Comment: BTW your sample output doesn't make sense. Department B should be Department2, no?

Comment: Yes, it was an typo and updated my question. Thanks for looking at it.

Answer (score 2):

You could do that as:

```
SELECT 
   ID, 
   Name,
   Max(case when department = 'A' then 'A' end) as Department1,
   Max(case when department = 'B' then 'B' end) as Department2,
   Max(case when department = 'C' then 'C' end) as Department3,
   MAX(Value1) AS Value1, 
   MAX(Value2) AS Value2, 
   MAX(Value3) AS Value3 
FROM Employee
GROUP BY Id, Name;
```

Thinking it is just for some kind of pivot like display.

UPDATE: I am not really sure if you meant as in your sample though (would be nice if your question is clear):

```
WITH
  x AS (
         SELECT
              Name, Department, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Department) AS dept
         FROM Employee
       )
SELECT
         t.Type                                        AS ID
       , t.Name
       , MAX(CASE WHEN x.dept=1 THEN x.Department END) AS Department1
       , MAX(CASE WHEN x.dept=2 THEN x.Department END) AS Department2
       , MAX(CASE WHEN x.dept=3 THEN x.Department END) AS Department3
       , MAX(Value1)                                   AS Value1
       , MAX(Value2)                                   AS Value2
       , MAX(Value3)                                   AS Value3
FROM     Employee t
         INNER JOIN x ON x.Name=t.Name
GROUP BY t.Type, t.Name
ORDER BY t.Name;
```

[DBFiddle demo is here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=309b6018f54976671558dc94bee1012c)

Comment: Apologies for not providing the problem properly. I have updated the question again.

Comment: Thank you. You second solution of applying dense rank worked like charm !

Comment: @Born2Code, in my reply, first one already covers the updated one. Second one is if you wanted it in your original output.